# Get the names of all empty tables in a SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to get the names of all the empty tables in a sqlite database. I tried both of these lines but neither worked:

1. `SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and COUNT(*) = 0`
2. `SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) = 0`

Is it possible to do what I want in one command? Or do I have to break it down to multiple commands?

Comment: What are the outputs of both of those queries?

Comment: You could use UNION to combine queries as long as they both have same number of columns as result.

Comment: @steveclark the first command results in "Error: misuse of aggregate function COUNT() and the second command just does nothing at all

Comment: @iamshahid What do you mean by combine queries? Do you mind showing me what you mean?

Comment: Well I was answering second part of your problem, which is running both queries as one command. You cannot use aggregate in WHERE condition, it needs to be in the COLUMN place instead. Which programming language you are using? You should be able to get the result of the query and if count returns less than 1 that means, the table is empty.

Comment: @iamshahid Ah yah well the only alternative I could think was doing a query of all table names and then looping over them and checking if they were empty. I am using sqlite3 for python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's the way forward for your current scenario. Python can deal with the rest by checking query result as mentioned. Best wishes.

Comment: @Kylie `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` on each table you're trying to check should be able to count the rows of each table.  Assuming your original query `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'` returns the list of only the name of every table you're  trying to check you just need to do a nested query. Something like `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table')`

Comment: Hm `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table')` only gives me the total count of all tables